# Mediapipe without Face detector is Possible?

Tags: face-detection, mediapipe, face-landmark

Is there a way to operate only the face mesh without the face detector in the face feature detection guide? (https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/face_landmarker/python)

As a face detector, I want to use the model I developed, but the examples always seem to include a face detector. Is there a way?

Face mesh detection without face detector, it only use face-cropped image input.